# How to get specific column using Android Room

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to get `id` column from my database, ad it to ArrayList and to each id add "\t0",

My database is created using Room, i have a lot of column which one of them is

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
```

I am operating using `ItemDAO` and i have there function

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM item")
List<Item> getItems();
```

Which writes to `ArrayList<Items>` all of contents 
I was thinking of running it trough the loop getting `id` and adding to `ArrayList<String>` but this doesn't seems to be eficient.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit] your question accordingly. Like: What database (SQlite, Realm, etc), how did the id get into the database? What have you tried so far?

Comment: How about now??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT Id FROM item")
List<Integer> getAllIds();
```

Your model:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "Id")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
```

In you query `SELECT * FROM item` * means select All, put there your column name and you will get list of objects from that column

Example: Select all items in id column `SELECT id FROM item`

Comment: Do i have to write a loop rewriting it to List<String> ?

Comment: Yes, u need to rewrite it, because Room returns int values

Comment: @Valgaal can you actually write the code for what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to modify and test @Valgaal 's solution. It turns out that Room can also return other type of values, more than just id (or integer).

For example, you can write an item class like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = Item.TABLE_NAME)
public class Item {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ItemsTable";
    public static final String COL_DESC = "Description";

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = COL_DESC)
    private String description;

    // getter & setter...
}
```

And then, you can write Dao like this:

```
@Dao
public interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Item.TABLE_NAME)
    List<Item> getItems();

    @Query("SELECT " + Item.COL_DESC + " FROM " + Item.TABLE_NAME)
    List<String> getItemDescriptions();
}
```

And it's functional as it should be.
I guess all of the other data types that Room can save (including custom types?) can be queried (and returned lists of specific column data) by the same logic above. Hope this would help someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

For returning multiple columns, create a `pojo class` that can be set as a return type for your `DAO function`

Note the select query should contain the Pojo class variable name (can be done via *AS keyword*)

Detailed answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802209/1029110

I landed on this question for my issue...but didnt find answer. So this may help others.